# Can't import posts in multisite

Tags: multisite, import

I set up a multisite in my local environment (MAMP), and when I try to import posts in either of the 2 sites I have, I get this error:

> Sorry, there has been an error.
>   File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

The file I've tried to upload is very small (49Kb), so I know it's not that, and it's not empty.

When I upload on a non multisite WP, the import goes without any issues.

Is it a setting in multisite I need to change?

Comment: You should be able to import from a WXR file in Multisite the same as in single-site WP. You've double-checked the content of your file?

Comment: @PatJ Yes, I was able to import into a non-multisite the exact same file... I'm starting to think that I may have to uninstall, and install again. I was hoping it was a settings thing (I'm new to multisite), but it seems it's not.

Comment: I'd double-check the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` constants in `php.ini` first, and also make sure that the `wp-content/uploads` folder has permissions that will allow files to be uploaded, before I reinstalled.